# Take something down or off the cupboard

Tags: word-usage

In the two situations,do my sentences sound natural?

If something is kept on the cupboard/closet, what should I use(if either of them sounds natural)

> Can you take it off/down the closet(cupboard)?

And if I have to put something on the cupboard/closet:

> Put it on the cupboard(closet).

(It doesn't have to be put inside but on it.)

Answer (score 2):

If it is kept *on* the cupboard, you would "take it off the cupboard".

However must cupboards are boxes or small rooms, and you put thing *in* the cupboard. In which case you should say "take it out the cupboard".  Putting things "on" a cupboard is odd enough that I'd probably want to emphasise with a phrase like "on top of"

> Take the pen that is on top of the cupboard
>
> You can put it on top of the cupboard

Comment: Yes it is kept on top of the cupboard.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are unusual.

Items are usually kept:

> IN cupboards/closets
>   or
>   ON cupboard shelves
>   or
>   ON top OF cupboards

So most people would take items:

> DOWN FROM the top of the cupboard
>   or
>   OUT OF the cupboard
>   or
>   FROM the cupboard

Yes, you could put it ON a cupboard. We generally say **on top of** to make it clear that we don't want it placed on shelf.